# Symfony: passing variables in a template without rendering it

Tags: php, templates, twig, symfony

I have a base twig template that is being extended by all the user twig templates, I have a main navigation in the base template that contains the profpic of the user, I want to pass the profpic variable to base template while rendering the index template of user via same controller.. how do I do this?

Please help..

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Basically you could pass variables from one template to another like: {% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}, but I am not sure I correctly understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want make that ?

```php
$html = $this->renderView('AccueilBundle:Reservation:billet.html.twig', array(
            'reservation'  => $reservation));
```